# Visual Studio 2012 error C2248 in std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with the Visual Studio 2012 implementation of the `std::thread` class.

```
Error C2248: "std::thread::thread": cannot access private member declared in class std::thread
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0 line: 606
```

A.hpp:

```
class A{ 
    public:
        A();
        ~A();


    private:
        vector<thread> listOfThreads;       
        int numberOfProcessorCores;
        int startUpWorkerThreads();
};
```

A.cpp:

```
    int A::startUpWorkerThreads(){
        if(numberOfProcessorCores <= 0) return 2; //Keine Angabe zur Anzahl der Prozessorkerne
        if(listOfThreads.size() > 0) return 3; //Bereits initialisiertdefiniert

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessorCores; i ++){
            thread newThread(&TaskManagement::TaskManager::queueWorker);            
            listOfThreads.push_back(newThread);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This is the part of my programm where the thread-class is used.

Does anybody know why this error occures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that an operation is attempting to call `std::thread`'s copy constructor or assignment operator, both of which are deleted or private. As an alternative, you can "move" a thread into the vector by pushing a temporary like this:

```
listOfThreads.push_back(thread(&TaskManagement::TaskManager::queueWorker));
```

otherwise, you could call `std::move` on your thread object, which leaves you with a thread object in the same state as a default constructed one (thanks to @JonathanWakely for pointing that out in comments). In your case, there is no reason to create a thread and explicitly move it.

Comment: I´ve tried this but now I´m getting:
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional line: 1152

Comment: @Xenogenesis well, whatever you pass to the thread constructor has to evaluate to something that can be called without arguments. Or you can pass the function name /functor instance followed by a list of arguments. So `TaskManagement::TaskManager::queueWorker` doesn't seem to resolve to something you can call without arguments.

Comment: `void TaskManager::queueWorker(){`
 taskDelegator(Task());
`}`

This is the queueWorker function.
TaskDelegator is a function pointer defined by:
`typedef void (*TaskDelegator)(Task);`

And Task is a struct containing an integer.
So at least there are no arguements :(

Comment: @Xenogenesis unless `TaskManager::queueWorker()` is static, it takes an implicit first argument of type `TaskManager*`.

Comment: Oh, i didn´t know that.
Do you have an example of creating such a thread?

Comment: @Xenogenesis `TaskManager tm; std::thread t1(TaskManagement::TaskManager::queueWorker, &tm);

Comment: There's nothing weird about the state, it's identical to the state of a default-constructed `std::thread`

Comment: @JonathanWakely is that guaranteed by the standard? If so, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed by [thread.thread.constr]/9 "_Effects:_ Constructs an object of type `thread` from `x`, and sets `x` to a default constructed state."

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` doesn't have a copy constructor, which is needed to perform `push_back` and, probably, for other `vector` operations.

Comment: Hmm ok, do you know a possible way to store created thread objects?
Or isn´t it possible?

Comment: @Xenogenesis it is possible. See my answer.